# Custom adapter of interface object in Android

Tags: android, listview, interface, adapter

In my Android Application I've some objects which represent different kinds of operations.

```
public class OperacionDivisa implements IOperacion {
public class OperacionLargo implements IOperacion {
public class OperacionMedio implements IOperacion {
public class OperacionOpciones implements IOperacion {
```

Each kind of operation implements IOperation interface so I can make an ArrayList of IOperations and store all operations in a single ArrayList.

Now I'd like to do the inverse process. I want to get the arraylist of operations from Firebase (which has already been achieved) and I'd like to show the operations in a ListView

I created a custom adapter as follows:

```
public class ListViewAdapterOperaciones extends ArrayAdapter<IOperacion>
```

The issue is that I need to cast each object to its original class to show in a textview different attributes. So this is not useful.

```
IOperacion operacion = (IOperacion) getItem(position);
```

So, for each object I'd like to show some data in the listView but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` statement (or similar) to check `instanceof`, then use the objects as the subclass.

```
if (operacion instanceof OperacionLargo) {
  // Large operation
} else if (operacion instanceof OperacionDivisa) {
  // Other operation
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks a lot, @WoogieNoogie